# Selecting an adjacent's child... how?

Tags: css, css-selectors

trying to select an adjacent's child element with CSS... not really sure how to
This is the HTML structure

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            First level
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second level</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to say that there is a menu with multiple levels. When theres a UL existing within a LI then the  needs to have a dropdown/expand icon... so I thought if I use the adjacent selector I can determine if this level has kids to expand and this is what I thought would work but didn't:

```
ul li a ~ ul .icon {
    // doesnt work
}
ul li a .icon ~ ul {
    // doesnt work
}
```

This works but I need to target the .icon

```
ul li a ~ ul {
    // works
}
```

Cheers, Dom

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't backtrack with CSS selectors. It has to be after; it can't be before.

Comment: How is the HTML generated? Or is it static? If you have control over how the DOM is generated I guess a workaround would be to attach a `class="has-submenu"` or something similar, to the outer li, if the list item has a sub-menu. And then use that to select.

Comment: Added an example of the above solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon my comment on your question. If you have control over how the HTML for the menu is generated, a workaround would be to add an extra class to each li-element that has a sub-menu. Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            First level
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second level</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you could use a selector like this:

```
.has-submenu .icon {
    /* Do your stuff here */
}
```

Comment: thanks, I guess the answer is no it's not possible then :D Will have to add the class as suggested

Comment: @DominicWatson Yeah, I'm afraid your stuck with that. CSS is a bit limited sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

ul is a child of li, not the anchor. So `ul li ul` .
If you want to select it as a sibling, then `ul li a + ul`

Comment: That is understandable, but actually the question was to target the element (`li`) (no matter how deep in the tree) has an other `ul` to manipulate some element before (`.icon`)

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't do it. It think he is looking for something like an if-statement in CSS (which doesn't exist). If the li-element contains another ul, then he want's to modify the .icon span within the anchor.